# Table column alignment in Wordpress about page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I am trying to add a table with tree columns in my Wordpress about page. Here is the code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://olcayertas.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/portrate.jpg?w=284" alt="Olcay Ertaş" title="Olcay Ertaş" />
    </td><td width="20"/>
    <td>
        Olcay Ertaş
        <a href="http://twitter.com/olcayertas">Twitter</a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/olcayertass">Facebook</a>
        <a href="http://instagram.com/mrjamesreeves">Linkedin</a>
        <a href="mailto:james@bigamericannight.com">Email</a>
        <a href="http://www.bigamericannight.com/files/James%20Reeves.pdf" target="_blank">CV</a>
        Galatasaraylıyım
        Samsunluyum
        Koç burcundanım
    </td>
</tr>
```

It looks like this in designer:
[image]
But it looks like different in page:
[image]
I want it look like this:
[image]
Here is the page link: http://www.olcayertas.com/hakkimda/
And here is the page Iam inspired: http://bigamericannight.com/information/

Here is the code with @Ali suggested and its result:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<img title="Olcay Ertaş" alt="Olcay Ertaş" src="http://olcayertas.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/portrate.jpg?w=284" />
</td>
<td width="20"></td>
<td style="position:absolute;">
Olcay Ertaş
<a href="http://twitter.com/olcayertas">Twitter</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/olcayertass">Facebook</a>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=73448442">Linkedin</a>
<a href="mailto:olcayertas@gmail.com">Email</a>
<a href="" target="_blank">CV</a>
Galatasaraylıyım
Samsunluyum
Koç burcundanım
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the link of your live page?

Comment: @aligajani I have added the page link

Comment: See my answer. It works, tried and tested.

Comment: @aligajani I do not know what is the problem but I updated question with your suggestion and its result.

Comment: Check the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting my page with Firefox inspecter, I have found that my global css file is using `vertical-align: baseline` for `td` elements. I have used same keyword in my table and problem have been solved.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="stats" valign="top" width="310">
            <img src="http://olcayertas.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/portrate.jpg?w=284" alt="Olcay Ertaş" title="Olcay Ertaş" />
        </td>
        <td class="stats" width="20">
        </td>
        <td class="myclass" style="vertical-align: middle">
            <div class="name">Olcay Ertaş</div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="stats">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/olcayertas">Twitter</a><br>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/olcayertass">Facebook</a><br>
                    <a href="http://instagram.com/mrjamesreeves">Linkedin</a><br>
                    <a href="mailto:james@bigamericannight.com">Email</a><br>
                    <a href="http://www.bigamericannight.com/files/James%20Reeves.pdf" target="_blank">CV</a><br>
                    Galatasaraylıyım<br>
                    Samsunluyum<br>
                    Koç burcundanım<br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks to everybody for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use **DIV** for this, but you use **TABLE**, no problem try this code it works correctly

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="stats" valign="top" width="310">
            <img src="http://olcayertas.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/portrate.jpg?w=284" alt="Olcay Ertaş" title="Olcay Ertaş" />
        </td>
        <td class="stats" width="20">
        </td>
        <td class="stats" valign="top">
            <div class="name">Olcay Ertaş</div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="stats">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/olcayertas">Twitter</a><br>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/olcayertass">Facebook</a><br>
                    <a href="http://instagram.com/mrjamesreeves">Linkedin</a><br>
                    <a href="mailto:james@bigamericannight.com">Email</a><br>
                    <a href="http://www.bigamericannight.com/files/James%20Reeves.pdf" target="_blank">CV</a><br>
                    Galatasaraylıyım<br>
                    Samsunluyum<br>
                    Koç burcundanım<br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a hack, but you can add an inline CSS style to your `<td>`

For example, like this. Add the `style="position:absolute;"` to your `td`.

```
<td style="position:absolute;">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/olcayertas">Twitter</a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/olcayertass">Facebook</a>
    <a href="http://instagram.com/mrjamesreeves">Linkedin</a>
    <a href="mailto:james@bigamericannight.com">Email</a>
    <a href="http://www.bigamericannight.com/files/James%20Reeves.pdf" target="_blank">CV</a>
    Galatasaraylıyım
    Samsunluyum
    Koç burcundanım
</td>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works here, look at the picture. You didn't add it properly.

Comment: @OlcayErtaş Saying "it did not work" tells us nothing. What about it "didn't work"? What is it doing that constitutes a non-working state?